# Getting error [PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type]

Tags: plsql

I have a stored procedure which is driving me nuts. I know it's a pretty simple thing, but I think I am not able to figure it out.

I am getting the error

> "PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type"

in below line:

```
-- Write the result into Log
v_LogText := 'Summary Elapsed Time: ' || TO_CHAR(floor((cast(SYSTIMESTAMP as date) - Cast(v_StartTime as date)) * 86400)) || 'sec Batchsize ' || TO_CHAR (v_BatchSize);
Std.Log (v_WorkerName,'001','CAS', '0', 'en', ' 00000000', v_LogText );
```

Declarations:

```
v_LogText NVARCHAR2(2000); 
v_BatchSize NUMBER(10,0) := iv_BatchSize; [ and iv_BatchSize is passed in the procedure as a paramenet like "iv_BatchSize IN NUMBER DEFAULT NULL"]
v_StartTime DATE := SYSDATE;
```

I already tried to change SYSTIMESTAMP to SYSDATE but no luck.

Comment: You need to post little bit more of your code. it may happen the error might be arising from somewhere else.

Comment: Updated some more lines.

Comment: Which line is failing? You posted several lines.

Comment: Hi William, Line v_LogText := 'Summary Elapsed Time: ' || TO_CHAR(floor((cast(SYSTIMESTAMP as date) - Cast(v_StartTime as date)) * 86400)) || 'sec Batchsize ' || TO_CHAR (v_BatchSize); was failing. I just confirmed today the solution provided by Raj worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the amount of information provided, please check below way to do it. Hope this works for you.

```
declare
v_LogText NVARCHAR2(2000); 
v_BatchSize NUMBER(10,0) := 76363;
v_StartTime DATE := SYSDATE;

a varchar2(100);
begin

select TO_CHAR(floor((cast(SYSTIMESTAMP as date) - Cast(v_StartTime -1 as date)) * 86400)) 
into a
from dual;


v_LogText := 'Summary Elapsed Time: ' || a || 'sec Batchsize ' || TO_CHAR (v_BatchSize); 

dbms_output.put_line(v_LogText);

end;
```